# Atom editor custom made file template

Tags: html, keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

I currently use ATOM as my text editor for HTML files and etc. My headers, nav bar, and footer are usually all the same. Is there a way or package that I can install that will allow me to have this autocomplete as a shortcut for any HTML file that I am working on?

Example:

I open an atom file
Save as HTML
Type in a button or do something
Page will have all my custom made HTML code

That way I don't have to re-entering it or etc.

Comment: Switch to VScode. It's easy than atom.

Comment: @ŕ̷͉ge̸ḓ̶̅i̷t viscose can do this?

Comment: Yes.. Give VSCODE a try

Comment: That's hardly an answer to the question - there's nothing wrong with Atom.

Comment: @ŕ̷͉ge̸ḓ̶̅i̷t got a link on how to do this via vscode?

Comment: @JohnP can Atom do this?

Comment: Yes - see my answer below (just posted).

Answer (score 0):

To do this in Atom, you're probably looking for the [snippets](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/) feature. This lets you auto-insert arbitrary content as you need, and you can specify your own snippets - like your standard header, footer etc. You can even create shortcuts so your snippets are automatically expanded.

Once you've found the snippets feature, do let us know if you have any problems getting it to do exactly what you need. Most text editors will have something similar - it's a common use case.